# Elasticsearch indexing speed with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch indice with a large amount of documents. I've been using javascript up until this point with Node.js. I made a cron job to run every 24 hours to update the documents individually based on any metadata changes. As some of you may know, this is probably the slowest possible way to do it. Single threaded Node.js with individual indexing on Elasticsearch. When I run the cron job, it runs at a snails pace. I can update a document every maybe 1.5-2 seconds. This means it would take around 27 hours to update all the docuemnts. I'm using a free-tier AWS ES instance so I don't have access to certain features that would help me speed up the process.

Does anyone know of a way to speed up the indexing? If I were to call for a bulk update, how would that manifest in javascript? If I were to use another language to multi-thread it, what would be the fastest option?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question "If I were to call for a bulk update, how would that manifest in javascript?".

Bulk update should be the best solution irrespective of any language/framework. Of-course, you can explore other languages like Ruby to leverage threads to make bulk update more distributed and fast.

From experience, a bulk update with a batch size b/w 4-7k works just fine. You may want to fine tune the size in this range.

Ensure the value of `refresh_interval` is set to a very great value. This will ensure that the documents are not indexed very frequently. IMO the default value will also do. Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-refresh.html#refresh-api-desc).